# Create dyadic pairwise dataset based on conditions

Tags: r, data-manipulation, pairwise

I have a monadic dataset that looks something like this:

```
df<-structure(list(Number = c("375_1", "375_1", "375_1", "375_1", 
"375_1", "375_1", "375_1", "375_1", "647_1", "647_1", "647_1", 
"647_1", "647_1", "647_1", "647_1", "647_1", "647_1", "647_1", 
"647_1", "647_1"), year = c(1973, 1973, 1973, 1973, 1973, 1973, 
1973, 1973, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 
1981, 1981, 1981), Country = c("AUT", "PRT", "CHE", "NOR", "SWE", 
"ISL", "DNK", "GBR", "BRA", "CHL", "EGY", "IND", "ISR", "MEX", 
"PER", "KOR", "PAK", "PHL", "TUN", "TUR")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to transform this dataset to have a dyadic structure based on the `Number` column. In other words, for every different `Number`, I would like to create pairs of observations for all the combinations of countries.
The "head" of the final dataset should look something like this:

```
final <- data.frame(Number = c("375_1", "375_1", "375_1", "375_1", "375_1", "375_1", "375_1","375_1", "375_1", "375_1", "375_1","375_1"), 
                    year = c(1973, 1973, 1973, 1973, 1973, 1973, 1973, 1973,1973, 1973, 1973, 1973), 
                    Country1 = c("AUT", "AUT", "AUT", "AUT", "AUT", "AUT", "AUT","PRT","PRT","PRT","PRT","PRT"), 
                    Country2 = c("PRT", "CHE", "NOR", "SWE", "ISL", "DNK", "GBR","CHE","NOR","SWE", "ISL","DNK"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

and continue like this for every country dyad within the group.
I would like to find a clean and concise way to do so

Thank you very much in advance for your help

Comment: The `final` dataframe provide a glimpse of how the final output should look like. because I had to write it manually and writing all of it would have taken ages. I guess one could consider the `final` data frame as the `head()` of the output. Meaning that in the real output I would like to have for every value of the variable `Number` all possible combination of dyads.

Comment: Any idea for dealing with the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, I think that the solution is the following

```
final <- df %>% group_by(Number, year)%>%  expand(Country1 = Country, Country2= Country) %>% filter(Country1!=Country2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  full_join(df, by=c("Number", "year")) %>%
  filter(Country.x != Country.y)
```